# How can I partition a new external HD as a Time Machine backup AND also for manual copy/paste drag/drop on macOS Monterey 12.4?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, time-machine

I have an older 3TB drive from the same manufacturer and that drive has 1 partition (Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)) which is both a Time Machine backup AND it also allows me to copy/paste files onto it without the need for multiple partitions. I just purchased a 5TB version and erased it using Disk Utility, however when I set it up for Time Machine backups I can then no longer create folders in the root or copy any files manually into it.

How can I partition this new 5TB drive—ideally with 1 partition—so that I can use it as a Time Machine backup AND also manually copy/paste files/folders to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time Machine drives are not meant to be shared-purpose. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should.* Apple have tightened up on this in successive OSes.

On Monterey, Time Machine must be APFS, HFS+ is no longer accepted. Shared purpose is also no longer accepted. I don't know why you'd want Case-Sensitive. Apple pretends it's OK with it, but actually it doesn't handle it very well at all & some apps will fail with it. Unless your system is also set to use Case-Sensitive, I'd avoid it.

To set up a new drive, just format in Disk Utility [ <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>  to see devices not just volumes] using Erase [image]. Set GUID/APFS. Once completed, then add a second partition [image], either HFS+ or APFS for your portable data. Disk Utility will query your decision. You *do* want a new partition, not new volume. This will just take away some of the tighter controls the system would otherwise place on it.

[image]